# Is perfectly diffuse reflection entropy maximizing?

Tags: optics, entropy, reflection

Suppose that I shine light on a surface and none of it will be absorbed or transmitted, and the spectrum doesn't change (so that all that's left to determine is the power reflected from the surface as a function of solid angle).

Is there a sense in which diffuse reflection (following Lambert's cosine law) is maximizing the entropy change of the light from before the reflection to after it?

Comment: If you are looking for an optical entropy maximization machine, look no further than a black body.

Answer (score 2):

It's maximizing the angular entropy in the sense that far more "available" angle vectors are inhabited.   I suspect you need to be careful with the word "entropy" here.  For example, the photons are not down-converted into a larger number of photons of longer wavelength (aka 'heat death of the universe').

Comment: Hi Carl, is it possible to be more precise? We do not spread the light out evenly among all solid angles; instead the intensity per unit solid angle obeys Lambert's law.

Comment: Well, that's true too, so you may not really be maximizing even the solid-angle-entropy.